JsonApiDotNetCore and filtering using a udf
I am using JsonApiDotNetCore, .NET Core, and EF Core on SQL Server and creating a REST project implementing the Json API standard.
I have plenty of resources (models) but one of them has some fields that are encoded.
For example, I have a table Customers that has columns that are encoded using a DB symmetric key (not important here).
I have a database user-defined function
nvarchar dbo.DecryptData(byte[])

that performs the decryption of these columns and I want to be able to write a JSON API filter like this:
/api/v1/customer?filter=equals(DecryptData(firstName), 'Theodore')

and this to be translated in the EF Core query like
WHERE dbo.DecryptData(firstName) = 'Theodore'

Customers.FirstName is a varbinary column in the database and is mapped as byte[] in my resource
Is this type of filtering possible?
I've tried several suggestions for CoPilot/ChatGpt by overriding the OnApplyFilter but nothing has worked so far.
Any ideas?

AI is not so smart as you think, start reading documentation Custom query string parameters. Never seen this library, so no more help. How to map C# function to database is another reading User-defined function mapping
